How to set the CRS correctly PyQGIS to display points on top of OSM basemap
I want to load OSM as a background map and plot some points on top of it. And I want to use PyQGIS to write to a QGIS project file because that's the easiest way to share the data with my particular team.
As a super basic example I got the latitude and longitude for two points from Google Maps and saved them to a CSV file. For context, the two points are located in Vienna, Austria. This is the exact content of the CSV file I will be loading in the code further down:
id,       latitude,    longitude
4820189,  48.1847181,  16.3038135
3840104,  48.1943063,  16.319905

According to Wikipedia's article on EPSG:3857, both Google Maps and OSM are using this CRS. So I was expecting to be able to just load each layer and they would be displayed as expected. But I can't get them to play along.
I'm using the following code. I provide the same CRS in both cases. But the points get displayed at the null island (see screen capture). What am I missing? I'm listing the things I tried after the code excerpt.
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

qgsApp = QgsApplication([], False)
qgsApp.initQgis()
project = QgsProject.instance()

project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857"))

osmLayer = QgsRasterLayer( 
    "type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857", 
    "OpenStreetMap",
    "wms",
)
osmLayer.setOpacity(0.5)
project.addMapLayer(osmLayer)

pointsLayer = QgsVectorLayer(
    "file:///.../points.csv?yField=latitude&xField=longitude&crs=epsg:3857",
    "pointsFromCsv",
    "delimitedtext",
)
project.addMapLayer(pointsLayer)

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(osmLayer.extent())
canvas.setLayers([osmLayer])

project.setFileName("path/to/output-project-file.qgs")
project.write()


Things I've tried already:
When setting the CRS to &crs=EPSG4289 for the OSM layer and to &crs=epsg:4289 for the points layer, the points are displayed roughly right. They're a bit shifted, which I assume is because 4289 isn't 100% the right one. See the screen capture below. Note that the project CRS needs to be set to EPSG:3857, otherwise the points are back at the null island. I really don't get this! Why would it work when the various layers are given a different CRS and what does the project CRS actually do?


The problem is that you have told QGIS that your CSV points are in EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) and they are not, so they end up in the wrong place when QGIS accepts the values as metres when they are degrees.
Change your input line to:
pointsLayer = QgsVectorLayer(
    "file:///.../points.csv?yField=latitude&xField=longitude&crs=epsg:4326",
    "pointsFromCsv",
    "delimitedtext",
)

so that QGIS knows it needs to convert from degrees (EPSG:4326) to metres.

thank you, it seems to work closely enough. can you help me make sense of why it works, though? i set the project's crs to 3857, and did the same for osm (&crs=EPSG3857). and then i read that google maps uses 3857 too. so the natural assumption i made was to copy the lat,lon coordinates from google maps and expect them to show at the right place on the map in my project. does google maps use a different crs after all?

Setting "&crs=EPSG:3857" on the VectorLayer tells QGIS to read in your values in metres and display them unchanged on the map (as the projections match) so your lat/lon measurements are in degrees show up close to what we call Null Island (which is at 0,0).
